# 301 Redirect's eliminating part of URL

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I'm redesigning a website and working in a staging setting. The domain is going to remain the same but various pages are moving around or being replaced with new pages.

I need to put 301 redirects in place to make sure the old pages redirect to the new ones. But I'm struggling with the best way to do this.

I found the syntax for 301 directs using htaccess and was testing with the staging site as follows for a few urls:

```
Redirect 301 /staging/blog https://example.com/staging/
Redirect 301 /staging/research/papers https://example.com/staging/research/countries/
Redirect 301 /staging/research/papers/report https://example.com/staging/research/countries/country/activities
```

But I am finding that when I implement this the redirect for the third page here redirects to:
https://example.com/staging/research/countries/activities
(missing out the counry page entirely)

Could anyone help me with why this is? And/or explain how I should be doing this?

Comment: Welcome to SO, thanks for sharing your rules. Could you please do mention rules like from which page to which page you want to redirect? Like you are redirecting from `/staging/blog` TO `https://example.com/staging/` AND from `/staging/research/papers` TO `staging/research/countries/` what are the rules for  it? Kindly elaborate more on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Directives in configuration files (".htaccess" is a "distributed configuraton file") are processed from top to bottom. So you need to place more specific rules further up and less specific, more general rules further down:

```
Redirect 301 /staging/blog https://example.com/staging/
Redirect 301 /staging/research/papers/report https://example.com/staging/research/countries/country/activities
Redirect 301 /staging/research/papers https://example.com/staging/research/countries/
```

An alternative which allows for much more flexibility is offered by the rewriting module:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?staging/blog/?$ https://example.com/staging [R=301]
RewriteRule ^/?staging/research/papers/report/?$ https://example.com/staging/research/countries/country/activities [R=301]
RewriteRule ^/?staging/research/papers/?$ https://example.com/staging/research/countries [R=301]
```

Or the more general variant:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?staging/blog(.*)$ https://example.com/staging$1 [R=301]
RewriteRule ^/?staging/research/papers/report(.*)$ https://example.com/staging/research/countries/country/activities$1 [R=301]
RewriteRule ^/?staging/research/papers(.*)$ https://example.com/staging/research/countries$1 [R=301]
```

Your question, or better its examples, don't allow for a more precise answer. It is unclear whether the URLs to be redirected are meant as patterns (prefixes) or as final URLs.

And it is especially difficult to predict whether you will run into situations where you encounter rewriting loops. Which you would have to solve by adding conditions. Which is why you should learn more about how those directives work. You need to master that yourself. Which is why you should start reading the documentation of the modules the apache http server brings. They are of excellent quality and come with really great examples.